# Web Scraping getting error (HTTP Error 403: Forbidden) using urllib

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

I'm trying to automate web scraping on SEC / EDGAR financial reports, but getting HTTP Error 403: Forbidden. I've referred to similar Stack Overflow forms and have changed the code accordingly, but no luck so far.

```
test_URL = https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3662/0000950170-98-000413.txt
```

Code that I'm working with

```
import urllib

def get_data(link):
    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

    req = urllib.request.Request(link,headers=hdr)
    
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(req, timeout=10)
    content = page.read().decode('utf-8')
  
    return content

data = get_data(test_URL)
```

getting the error

```
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
             return result

~\Anaconda3n\lib\urllib\request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 
    651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

I've also tried using requests.get(test_URL) then using BeautifulSoup, but that doesn't return the whole text.
Is there any other approach we could follow?

Comment: Have you had success with this request before? Sometimes websites block IPs after they have made a huge amount of requests.

Comment: for the first time, it worked but after that, all I'm getting is this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had no probelems using the `request` package. I did need to add user-agent as without, I was getting the same issue as you. Try this:

```
import requests 

test_URL = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3662/0000950170-98-000413.txt'

def get_data(link):
    hdr = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Mobile Safari/537.36'}

    req = requests.get(link,headers=hdr)
    content = req.content
  
    return content

data = get_data(test_URL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add any headers to this request.
Try this

```py
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3662/0000950170-98-000413.txt')
print(r.text)
```

Comment: That’s not necessarily true.